# Hive Insert statement with or without select case sensitive

Tags: hive

I am running the following query

```
INSERT INTO TABLE X(A,B,C) select A,B,C FROM Y
FAILED: SemanticException 1:27 '[A, B, C]' in insert schema specification are not found among regular columns of default.X nor dynamic partition columns.. Error encountered near token 'C'
INSERT INTO TABLE X(a,b,c) select A,B,C FROM Y;
//no error
```

Why is the insert statement needs the column names to be lowercase ? If I perform a "show create table A" I am seeing the column names to be lower case is that the reason ?

Any answer is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Hive? Older versions do not support specification of specific columns in INSERT...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter hive version is 1.2

Comment: Your metastore is case sensitive, and stores all object names in lower case. Thus, column **A** does not exist, but column **a** does.

Comment: Kindly let me know how to change that also do I need to restart hive to make it effective ?